# What are the Lexing Errors in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I was trying to run a simple Feature file but i was getting Exception like :
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file.

which is Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error

i am trying to parametrized a When statement and got this Exception:

```
Scenario: Login to Gmail

  Given User is on Gmail login page
  When User enters <userName> and <pwd>
  And Clicks on login button
  Then User should redirect to home page

  scenario outline(tried Examples as well but didn't worked): 
  |userName   | pwd |
  |ravivani10 | abc |
```

Comment: please accept the below  answer by Jörn Horstmann if it solves your problem ? I had similar issue as yours by adding Scenario Outline it started working.

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax for a scenario outline is to start with the keyword **Scenario Outline:** and list the examples with the **Examples:** keyword.

```
Scenario Outline: Login to Gmail
  Given User is on Gmail login page
  When User enters <userName> and <pwd>
  And Clicks on login button
  Then User should redirect to home page
Examples:
  | userName   | pwd |
  | ravivani10 | abc |
```

Comment: It worked for me, in my case in Spanish syntax. I just had "Scenario: (Escenario:)" and it didn't work, but with "Scenario Outline: (Esquema del escenario:)" it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem but I was using correct syntax. Turns out my formatting was wrong, yes you read correctly: formatting. My scenario looked like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Confirm that hitting the endpoint returns the expected data
    Given uri url/to/a/service/to/test/param/{interval} and method GET
    And system user
    When I call the web service
    Then I expect that 'http status is' '200'
    And the following rules must apply to the response
        | element                     | expectation         | value                |
        | $                           | is not null         |                      |
        | objectType                  | value =             | Volume               |
        | objectData                  | is not null         |                      |
        | objectData                  | count =             | 1                    |
        | objectData[0].value         | is not null         |                      |
        | objectData[0].value         | data type is        | float                |
        | objectData[0].value         | value =             | <value>              |
    Examples:
        | interval | value     |
        | int1     | 355.77    |
        | int2     | 332.995   |
        | int3     | 353.71125 |
```

Above test will fail with Lexing Error. Now **take a look at the indentation of the Example** piece of my test (it is indented one level down the Scenario Ouline).

If I indent my test as follows (same level as Scenario Outline):

```
Scenario Outline: Confirm that hitting the endpoint returns the expected data
    Given uri url/to/a/service/to/test/param/{interval} and method GET
    And system user
    When I call the web service
    Then I expect that 'http status is' '200'
    And the following rules must apply to the response
        | element                     | expectation         | value                |
        | $                           | is not null         |                      |
        | objectType                  | value =             | Volume               |
        | objectData                  | is not null         |                      |
        | objectData                  | count =             | 1                    |
        | objectData[0].value         | is not null         |                      |
        | objectData[0].value         | data type is        | float                |
        | objectData[0].value         | value =             | <value>              |
Examples:
    | interval | value     |
    | int1     | 355.77    |
    | int2     | 332.995   |
    | int3     | 353.71125 |
```

Above test will pass. Totally dumb to me but that's how it works.

Comment: Right. I got this error too due to one word in my Then-line that began with capital letter. But I used small letter in my test class.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by not having the final `|` at the end of each line of data. That's not the reason for the OP but might help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

A lexing error from cucumber just means that the feature file wasn't in the format that cucumber is expecting.  This could be things like having a scenario title with no content or having the title "Feature: blah" twice.  This will happen even if the error isn't in the scenario that you are running.

The lexing error will usually give you a line number.  Can you post the line it complains about please?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and it was caused by having a space between the word 'Outline' and the colon symbol

```
Scenario Outline : Convert currencies
```

When I removed the space, I had this:

```
Scenario Outline: Convert currencies
```

..and the issue got resolved.

To find out the offender, check your error logs and you will find in the output the line number where the error lies. I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things: A) remove the spaces in Feature : and Scenario Outline : keywords; and B) change the Scenario Outline to Scenario (or add the missing examples for the outline).

If you run this feature:

Feature: Proof of concept that my framework works

Scenario: My first Test
  Given this is my first test
  When This is my second step
  Then This is the final step
Then cucumber will output the to-be-completed step definitions:

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^this is my first test$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^This is my second step$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^This is the final step$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end